# Proof of Convergence of Geometric Series with $\varepsilon$, $N$ without Logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove it by considering
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x}
$$
with the $\varepsilon - N$ definition.

I need to prove the existence of the least $N$ such that
$$
\frac{x^{N+1}}{1-x} \lt \varepsilon.
$$
So far I have only seen choices of $N$ involving the use of logarithms, which does not feel nice as logarithms have not yet been defined in the book I am following (Rudin). Is there any way to choose $N$ without logarithms? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to prove that, given $x\in ]0,1[$, you can choose $N$ such that $x^N$ is arbitrarily close de $0$. Suppose this is not the case. Let's note
$$a = \inf\, \{ x^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$
$a$ is clearly non-negative ; let's assume $a>0$. Then we have $a<\dfrac{a}{x}$, therefore there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a \leq x^n < \dfrac{a}{x}$. We then get $x^{n+1} < a$, which contradicts the definition of $a$.

Thus we have $ \inf\, \{ x^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}=0$, and therefore there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^{N} \leq \varepsilon \dfrac{1-x}{x}$. Hence
$$\dfrac{x^{N+1} }{1-x}< \varepsilon.$$